# Faster HTML5 video alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am trying to play a video and be able to fast-seek to different frames in the video on certain events. In the end, the video is supposed to play different keyframes based on music beats, so the trigger needs to be as exact as possible.

My first experiment was this: http://jsfiddle.net/QfvsE/ (click anywhere while playing)

It’s basically a test to see how fast `video.currentTime` was triggered, and as suspected the `<video>` element and API is too slow. It takes around 200ms before the video actually plays. This number quickly increases when using a source with higher resolution.

So I’m thinking alternatives like exporting a lot of JPEGS and then importing them in a canvas area and create a micro-api that triggers different frames. Would this be faster? Are there any other alternatives to play short snippets of film without flash, and be able to control it more exact?

FYI: This is all going to happen in a local environment using the latest chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a lots of JPEG file can reducing memory and computer performance,
if you want a faster connection that can stream the video, you can use `WebSocket API`

WebSocket can fix this case
 or use Flash

Comment: As said, this is happening in a local environment so websockets won't solve anything. And there is plenty of memory and computing power.

Comment: May be use canvas and xml as database

Comment: Me too, i want the api like you want to ...
Can we to join ?
Where i can contact you ?